# Add option to droplist and save it (html/js)

Tags: javascript, html

I seached on how to add options to a previous created droplist with js, but I want those added options to stay on the droplist so I can access them each time I access the webpage.
For example: Today I go the page and theres a droplist with option 1, 2 and 3. I add option 4. I want to go there tomorrow and see the 4 options... can I do it with simple html/js?

I'll leave my code (which isn't saving options-only adding them):

HTML:

```
Please choose an option :
<select id="droplist" name="droplist">
<option>1
<option>2
<option>3
</select>

<input id="newItem"></input>
<p><a href="#" onclick="add_option()">Add Item</a></p>
```

JS:

```
function add_option() { 
var x = document.getElementById("droplist");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = document.getElementById('newItem').value;
x.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store it in local storage with javascript, but that wouldn't be "forever". And it would only be store on the current computer.

At the very least, you need a serverside script to store it to a database, or to a simple text file. But it also seems like you would need a login system, if you want it to only show for you, not others.

TLDR; You need a serverside script like PHP or similar.

Comment: It's ok if it only stores it for me, I'm the only one who's visiting the page. Can you tell my how to store it with js? any function or something i can search...

Comment: [w3schools html5 webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) You could read about it here, and try out some functions. Trial and error is the best way to learn. :) Best of luck

Comment: If you feel I gave a satisfactory answer, please mark it as accepted as a sign of gratitude. Thanks :)